# Getting the XML from a response using the Authorize.Net PHP SDK

Tags: php, xml, authorize.net

I have written some functions using Authorize.Net's PHP SDK's that look like the following:

```
public function getCustomerProfiles() {
    $customerProfiles = array();

    // Before we can get customer profiles, we need to get a list of all customer id's.
    $customerIdListRequest = new AnetAPI\GetCustomerProfileIdsRequest();
    $customerIdListRequest->setMerchantAuthentication(self::getMerchantAuth(Config::LOGIN_ID, Config::TRANSACTION_KEY));

    $customerIdListController = new AnetController\GetCustomerProfileIdsController($customerIdListRequest);
    $customerIdListResponse = $customerIdListController->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);

    if(($customerIdListResponse != null) && ($customerIdListResponse->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok")) {
        // TODO: Investigate warning about no method named getIds().
        foreach( $customerIdListResponse->getIds() as $id ) {
            // Now we can get each customer profile.
            $request = new AnetAPI\GetCustomerProfileRequest();
            $request->setMerchantAuthentication(self::getMerchantAuth(Config::LOGIN_ID, Config::TRANSACTION_KEY));
            $request->setCustomerProfileId($id);

            $controller = new AnetController\GetCustomerProfileController($request);
            $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::SANDBOX);

            if(($response != null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok")) {
                // TODO: Investigate warning about no method named getProfile()

                // Add it to the array.
                array_push($customerProfiles, $response->getProfile()->xml);
            } else {
                throw new \Exception($response->getMessages()->getMessage());
            }

        }
    } else {
        throw new \Exception($customerIdListResponse->getMessages()->getMessage());
    }

    return $customerProfiles;
}
```

Currently, I'm just returning an array of objects. I'd prefer to get the raw XML response. Is this functionality available via Authorize.Net's PHP SDK? Or am I better of using something like Guzzle and making the request manually?

Comment: Why do you need the raw XML? What do you hope to do with that that the SDK doesn't already do for you?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/blob/9d24edc675362b6349983205b8288d178fa0c469/lib/net/authorize/api/controller/base/ApiOperationBase.php) I think it would be simple enough.

Look the `execute` method that is invoked by `executeWithApiResponse` there. See `xmlResponse`? Just need to store that as a class property (and add a public getter), or maybe tweak the function to take an extra argument telling it to return the raw response. Could hack it, or better yet, extend that `ApiOperationBase` class (note the interface `IApiOperation` gives you a outline to follow).

Seeing that `serializer` also...

```
$this->apiResponse = $this->serializer->deserialize( $xmlResponse, $this->apiResponseType , 'xml');
```

Could maybe do something more elegant with that. But not as clear as path I first described.

Comment: Editing third party libraries is generally considered a bad idea as it either prevents you from doing upgrades/updates as those changes tend to get lost breaking the calling code. It assumes that whomever is doing the update knows there are modifications, where they are, and what they are intended to do and that the updated source code still is written in such a way that the same hack can still be accomplished.